# Why prefer implicit val over implicit object

Tags: scala, design-patterns, implicit

When asking questions about implicits a common suggestion / recommendation / advice that is given together with the answer *(or sometimes that is the answer itself)* is to use `implicit vals` with **excplicit type signatures** instead of using `implicit objects`.

But, what is the reason behind that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104900/inherit-from-a-class-parametrized-by-an-inner-type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548968/how-to-use-functors-with-scala-cats/

Comment: @DmytroMitin thanks! I edited the answer to include the links to the gists you showed me the other day as well as adding the example of the first question. If you feel I missed something or that the answer could be more complete please let me know, or even if you want and can feel free to edit the answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*"TL;DR;"* The reason is that an `implici val` with an explicit type signature has the exact type you want whereas an `implicit object` has a different type.

The best way to show why that could be a problem is with a simple example:

```scala
// Having the following definitions.

trait SomeTrait[T] {
  def f: T
}

trait ExtendedTrait[T] extends SomeTrait[T] {
  def g: T
}

implicit val SomeStringVal: SomeTrait[String] = new SomeTrait[String] {
  override def f: String = "from val f"
}

implicit val ExtendedStringVal: ExtendedTrait[String] = new ExtendedTrait[String] {
  override def f: String = "from extended val f"
  override def g: String = "from extended val g"
}

implicit object ExtendedStringObject extends ExtendedTrait[String] {
  override def f: String = "from extended obj f"
  override def g: String = "from extended obj g"
}

// What will be the result of:
implicitly[SomeTrait[String]].f
```

Remember that:

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit parameter's type, the most specific one will be chosen using the rules of static overloading resolution.

Well then, the answer is: `"from extended obj f"`.
The above *(somewhat surprising)* result, is caused because objects have their own type *(singleton type `ExtendedStringObject.type` which is a subtype of `ExtendedTrait[String]`)*, as such, it is more **"specific"** than the others.

Now, the reason why that could be a problem is that most people are not aware that the `object` has its own type and that it is more specific than what they believe. Nevertheless, this could also make the `object` to be picked when you would not want it to be; for example:

```scala
// If instead we only had this:

implicit val ExtendedStringVal: ExtendedTrait[String] = new ExtendedTrait[String] {
  override def f: String = "from extended val f"
  override def g: String = "from extended val g"
}

implicit object ExtendedStringObject extends SomeTrait[String] {
  override def f: String = "from extended obj f"
}

// Then what will be the result of:
implicitly[SomeTrait[String]].f
```

In this case, we will have an *"ambiguous implicit values"* exception; because both options are equally **specific**.

---

#### Is the rules universal?

No.

As with most things in software engineering, nothing is universal.
There are cases where using an `implicit val` with an explicit type signature is either [not possible](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/0ef4c93b9a58a1f2e1d92f71fbdbfb19) *(for example, because the type is not writable in source code even if the compiler knows it exists)* or [it would not produce the correct result whereas an `implicit object` would do](https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/ed22c9a84d5c89a46148a073b92052da).
A simple example would be:

```scala
trait A {
  type X
}

object A {
  type Aux[XX] = A { type X = XX }
}

class B extends A {
  type X = T

  class T
}

implicit object b extends B
implicit object b1 extends B
```

Such that you can ask for `implicitly[A.Aux[b.T]]` whereas using `implicit val b: B = new B {}` would have not worked.
*(code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ery8xSKMSKKgZNJV19UgAQ/2) full context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64105099/4111404))*.

However, it could be said that those are rare *(advanced)* cases. As such, this could be considered a good guideline.