# How can I bring ad-hoc polymorphism using type classes or implicit classes into parameterized context at runtime?

Tags: scala

I have a set of ADTs like `Person` as mentioned below and a set of implicit class implementations (in my case). It worked all fine until I tried to abstract a common piece code in a method, say, `display` in this case. Not sure however, how to achieve this tough. I do understand the following errors but what I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this, if at all possible. Please suggest. TIA.

### Implicit Class Implementation

```scala
  case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)

  trait CustomStringifier {
    def stringify(): String
  }

  implicit class PersonCustomStringifier(person: Person) extends CustomStringifier {
    def stringify(): String = s"My name is ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}."
  }

  def display[T](obj: T): Unit = {
    println(obj.stringify())
  }

  display(Person("John", "Doe"))
```

This time I rightly get compile time error at line `println(obj.stringify)`: `Cannot resolve symbol stringify`.

### Type Class Implementation

```scala
  case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String)

  trait CustomStringifier[T] {
    def stringify(x: T): String
  }

  implicit object PersonCustomStringifier extends CustomStringifier[Person] {
    def stringify(person: Person): String =
      s"My name is ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}."
  }

  implicit class Stringifier[T](x: T) {
    def stringify(implicit stringifier: CustomStringifier[T]): String =
      stringifier.stringify(x)
  }

    def display[T](obj: T): Unit = {
      println(obj.stringify)
    }

  println(Person("John", "Doe").stringify)
```

I rightly get compile-time error at line `println(obj.stringify)`: `NO implicits found for parameter stringifier: CustomStringifier[T]`.

P.S. Let me know if I need to reframe this question to make more sense. Although, I tried to add multiple working pieces of code to indicate what I really need to achieve.

Comment: `display` doesn't work for any type `T`, it only works for types that have an instance of `CustomStringifier` associated with them. So you need to add that as another implicit parameter: `def display[T](obj: T)(implicit ev: CustomStringifier[T])` or use the context-bound sugar syntax: `def display[T : CustomStringifier](obj: T)`  - Note that it would be good to make `Stringifier` a value class to avoid instantiation when using the extension method and to [use an `implicit val` instead of an `object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258339/why-prefer-implicit-val-over-implicit-object).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for your suggestions. Both seem to work but they work only for type class implementations and not for implicit class implementation. I do see the reason though that your suggestions needs a concrete implementations but is there a way to achieve the same in case of implicit classes or do I need to make switch to type class implementation.

Comment: No, `implicit classes` are just a mean to add extension methods, not a mean of defining [**Polymorphism**](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4). - Maybe it can work if you use **structural types** but that would just be fragile and confusing.

Comment: You may also ask for an implicit conversion from `T` to `CustomStringifier` but at that point why not just ask for `CustomStringifier` directly and let implicit conversion work at the call site, that is also a common pattern known as the **magnet**.

Answer (score 2):

Type classes are resolved at compile so when you see this:

```
Person("John", "Doe").stringify
```

compiler produces this:

```
new Stringifier(Person("John", "Doe")).stringify(PersonCustomStringifier)
```

because it knows that `T=Person`, it needs `CustomStringifier[T]` from implicit scope, and that `PersonCustomStringifier` is such implicit.

In `stringify` method you have:

```
def stringify(implicit stringifier: CustomStringifier[T]): String =
  stringifier.stringify(x)
```

compiler don't know the type `T` BUT it knows that it has some `CustomStringifier[T]` that can be found in the implicit scope - because you passed it as an implicit argument. Then the responsibility to learn `T` and resolve associated `CustomStringfier[T]` is delegated/delayed to the caller (who might delegate it further if it also uses type parameters).

When you write:

```
def display[T](obj: T): Unit = {
  println(obj.stringify)
}
```

`T` is not known. There is no `CustomSerializer[T]` in scope, only `PersonCustomStringifier` - but we have no proof that `T=Person` so we cannot use it. That is why compilation fails.

To fix it you have to take implicit argument, deferring resolution to the caller

```
def display[T](obj: T)(implicit stringify: CustomStringifier[T]): Unit =
  println(obj.stringify)
```

which could be shortened to

```
def display[T: CustomStringifier](obj: T): Unit =
  println(obj.stringify)
```

Then when you will call

```
display(Person("John", "Doe"))
```

compiler will know that `T=Person` and will be able to figure out that `PersonCustomStringifier` is the right implicit to pass as implicit argument.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, typeclass in a nutshell is a generic function which resolves its implementation from finite number of concrete one via some mechanism (in our case, implicit search mechanism). In scala it consists of 4 components :

1. functional interface declaration (trait)
2. object which provides func(smth) alike syntax, companion to trait
3. finite set of implementations - implicit values
4. (optional) extension which provides smth.func syntax.

So, common usage of implicits looks like this, declaration:

```scala
trait YourTypeclass[T] {
  def doStuff(t: T): R
} 
object YourTypeclass {
  def apply[T](t: T)(implicit tInstance: YourTypeclass[T]): R = 
    tInstance.doStuff(t)
}
implicit YourTypeclassSyntax[T](val t: T) {
  def doStuff[T](implicit tInstance: YourTypeclass[T]): R = tInstance.doStuff(t)
}
```

Implementation:

```scala
case class YourClass()
object YourClass {
  implicit val yourTypeclassInstance: YourTypeclass[T] = {t => ???: R}
}
```

Usage:

```scala
val x: YourClass = ???
YourTypeclass(x)
x.doStuff
implicitly[YourTypeclass[T]].doStuff(t)
```

So why it is important to put instance to companion object? Because of implicit search order.Instances defined in companion objects avaliable from every place of project if they are not restricted with `private[package]` (**Implicit precedence** topic on Scala documentation).

You can also control which implicit you want to use by putting implicit instances in trait, then deeper implicit is, then lower priority it will be (usefull for generic ones and overrides, like `List[T]` vs `List[Int]`).

Second, for your special occasion `Show[T]` from cats exists.

Also there's short explanation there, with examples: https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses.html