# Type Classe implementation best syntax

Tags: scala, typeclass

When implementing Typeclasses for our types, we can use different syntaxes (an `implicit val` or an `implicit object`, for example). As an example:

A Typeclass definition:

```scala
  trait Increment[A] {
    def increment(value: A): A
  }
```

And, as far as I know, we could implement it for `Int` in the two following ways:

```scala
  implicit val fooInstance: Increment[Int] = new Increment[Int] {
    override def increment(value: Int): Int = value + 1
  }

// or

  implicit object fooInstance extends Increment[Int] {
    override def increment(value: Int): Int = value + 1
  }
```

I always use the first one as for Scala 2.13 it has an abbreviation syntax that looks like this:

```scala
implicit val fooInstance: Increment[Int] = (value: Int) => value + 1
```

But, is there any real difference between them? or is there any recommendation or standard to do this?

There is a [related question about implicit defs and implicit classes for conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286628/difference-between-conversion-with-implicit-function-and-implicit-class-in-scala), but I'm going more to the point of how to create (best practices) instances of Typeclasses, not about implicit conversions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between conversion with implicit function and implicit class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286628/difference-between-conversion-with-implicit-function-and-implicit-class-in-scala)

Comment: I am not sure `implicit object` qualifies as case of `implicit class` as it doesn't imply implicit conversion. It stops at defining `object` and letting it be seen as `implicit` value. `implicit class` has this extra step where the class' constructor is turned into a implicit function (which could be used to perform a conversion).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258339/why-prefer-implicit-val-over-implicit-object/65258340#65258340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the differences would be:

- `object`s have different initialization rules - quite often they will be lazily initialized (it doesn't matter if you don't perform side effects in constructor)
- it would also be seen differently from Java (but again, you probably won't notice that difference in Scala)
- `object X` will have a type `X.type` which is a subtype of whatever `X` extends or implements (but implicit resolution would find that it extends your typeclass, though perhaps with a bit more effort)

So, I wouldn't seen any difference in the actual usage, BUT the `implicit val` version could generate less JVM garbage (I say garbage as you wouldn't use any of that extra compiler's effort in this particular case).

Comment: Hey, I once created a wiki question / answer for exactly this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258339/why-prefer-implicit-val-over-implicit-object/65258340#65258340 - I was thinking, should we close this one and port your answer to that wiki? _(or as a separate answer, whatever you prefer)_ - Let me know WDYT :)

Comment: I am fine with both :)

Comment: I didn't find your wiki question @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez while searching for it, but your answer is really good. I'm fine with removing the question too and having both answers there, it seems cleaner in that way.

Comment: @JavierMontón no worries, I know I am not popular :c - jokes aside, if you feel the question is a duplicate we can close it like that; the important thing is that we could help you ;)  - Mateusz, could you please find some time to edit the wiki answer or add your own there? I will close this one as a duplicate as soon as I see you ported your answer there :D